# Unable to resolve service for type in Azure Microservice

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, microservices, azure-service-fabric

This is my first attempt creating microservices using Azure Service Fabric and .Net Core

In debug mode it works fine and I can hit the API end points using Postman. However when I tried to  hit same endpoints after publishing the Service Fabric application to Service Fabric Local Cluster (single node), it throws exception below

> Unable to resolve service for type '**UrlShortener.Services.Contracts.IUrlService**' while attempting to activate '**UrlShortener.WebService.Controllers.UrlShortenerController**'.

I am not sure what is missing here.

Here is my code snippet

### Controller

```
 public class UrlShortenerController : ControllerBase
 {
        private readonly IUrlService _urlService;

        public UrlShortenerController(IUrlService urlService)
        {
            _urlService = urlService;
        }
 }
```

### Service

```
public class UrlService : EntityService<Url>, IUrlService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IUrlRepository _repo;
    private readonly IOptions<ShortenUrlConfig> _config;
    public UrlService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IUrlRepository repo, IOptions<ShortenUrlConfig> config)
        : base(unitOfWork, repo)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _repo       = repo;
        _config     = config;
    }
```

}

### Service Extension

```
public static IServiceCollection RegisterCustomServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IUrlService, UrlService>();

            return services;
        }

        public static IServiceCollection RegisterRepositories(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IUrlRepository, UrlRepository>();
            return services;
        }
```

### Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.RegisterCustomContracts();
            services.RegisterCustomServices();
            services.RegisterRepositories();


            // configure the system messages
            services.Configure<ShortenUrlConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("ShortenUrlConfig"));

            services.AddEntityFramework(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TestDBContext"));
        }
```

Comment: Found nothing wrong in your code! Its mysterious!

Comment: What is the class definition of `UrlService`? Does it implement `IUrlService`?

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown because the `urlService` was not resolved in controller constructor, `UrlShortenerController(IUrlService urlService)` :

I suggest to call `services.AddMvc()` Method after registering services like this :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.RegisterCustomContracts();
     services.RegisterCustomServices();
     services.RegisterRepositories();
     services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

     // configure the system messages
     services.Configure<ShortenUrlConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("ShortenUrlConfig"));
     services.AddEntityFramework(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TestDBContext"));
}
```